# Python 'long' object has no attribute 'to_bytes'?

Tags: python, long-integer

I'm trying to use a bitcoin address validator written in Python from [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitcoin/address_validation#Python):

This snippet gives me trouble though:

```
def decode_base58(bc, length):
    n = 0
    for char in bc:
        n = n * 58 + digits58.index(char)
    return n.to_bytes(length, 'big')
```

I understand that n is either an int or a long, but neither has a method called to_bytes, so I don't really understand how this code could have ever worked?

Does anybody know what's wrong here? Am I doing something wrong, or is this code simply written wrong? All tips are welcome!

Comment: apparently to_bytes is a python3 method. it exists on int: https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/stdtypes.html#additional-methods-on-integer-types

Comment: (plus, the link you gave gives an alternative implementation for `to_bytes`)

Comment: @njzk2 - Alright thanks! So would you know how I can solve this in Python 2.7?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Python 2.7 `int` and `long` don't have the `.to_bytes` method. Python 3.2 `int` has the `.to_bytes` method.

A workaround for Python 2.x:

```
>>> length = 10
>>> n = 123456789
>>> ('%%0%dx' % (length << 1) % n).decode('hex')[-length:]
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07[\xcd\x15'
```

Comment: Alright, so do you know how I can make this work in Python 2.7?

Comment: can you similarly explain for 'from_bytes'?

Comment: @Abhiped: `myint = int(mystr.encode('hex'), 16)`

Answer (score 0):

This provided me th required result it was in the comments given by @martineau

```
''.join(chr((n >> i*8) & 0xff) for i in reversed(range(length)))
```

Comment: This works in Pythin 2, but it is slower (O(n**2) rather than O(n)) than the code in my answer.

Comment: yes I agree but this also works, thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score -1):

Since Python 3.2 the built-in integer types provide a `to_bytes` method.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes

Answer (score -2):

The code you linked contains :

```
assert n.to_bytes(length, 'big') == bytes( (n >> i*8) & 0xff for i in reversed(range(length)))
```

which means that you can define a `to_bytes` function:

```
def to_bytes(n, length):
    return bytes( (n >> i*8) & 0xff for i in reversed(range(length)))
```

And use it as such:

```
def decode_base58(bc, length):
    n = 0
    for char in bc:
        n = n * 58 + digits58.index(char)
    return to_bytes(n, length)
```

Comment: i just tested this on python 2.7. What part would you say does not work on python 2?

Comment: This doesn't work in Python 2.7.13. `to_bytes()` returns something like `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x021656E8>`. Also note that in Python 2, `bytes` is just an alias for `<type 'str'>`, so in that version this would work: `return ''.join(chr((n >> i*8) & 0xff) for i in reversed(range(length)))`.