# How to display values larger than 255 in Bytes in Python 3

Tags: python, byte

Believe it or not I've looked everywhere for this answer. How do I convert values larger than 255 into a `bytes` object in Python 3. I think this needs a byte string but I am not sure.

Example:

```
n = 257 
print(n) #Prints 257
n = bytes([n])
print(n) #ValueError: bytes must be in range(0, 256)
```

Comment: What do you want the result to be? A single byte is in the range [0, 255]. Presumably you want to convert your larger numbers into multiple bytes. What format? Little or big endian? Is it supposed to be unicode? etc.

Comment: This is for use in a "slider" of values.  I need to express very large values in byte form (like `n=500`) but clearly `bytes([n])` will not work here

Comment: What's a "slider" and what does "byte form" look like?

Comment: A numerical slider, in a GUI-based program (not really necessary info here).  My python code needs to read values from this slider.  Byte form would be whatever the `byte` value for `int` 500 is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`int` objects can be converted to bytes using the method `to_bytes`. However, you have to specify the number of bytes and byte order.

Example:

```
n.to_bytes(2, 'little')  # b'\x01\x01'
```

Comment: `bytes([n])` constructs a `bytes` object from an iterable of byte-like int (that is to say in `range(0, 256)`)

Comment: For us Python2.X users: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003021/python-long-object-has-no-attribute-to-bytes